# How to find which facebook friends use iPhone / iPod?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an iOS game, and would like to provide the options for users to invite their facebook friends. Since the game is only on iOS I would like to restrict the list to friends who have iphones, ipods, or ipads.

I'm hoping there is a way to see which friends have posted updates via Facebook for iOS, or some other way to get a list of ONLY friends with an iOS device.

I know there is a way to get a list of friends that have your app already installed, maybe you can do the same thing but send the request with the official facebook app id, instead of your own?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you sent a request with "the official facebook app id", this may also return friends that have the facebook app on phones and devices other than iPhone, iPod or iPad.

Answer (score 0):

follow this [instruction](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/), the function filter by device (iOS) is at bottom of instruction.